# getJSON each how to traverse to children objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the json below and I'm trying to traverse to the "results" and **get the question value or the incorrect answers values**

```
{
  "response_code": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "category": "Science & Nature",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "medium",
      "question": "Which part of the body does glaucoma affect?",
      "correct_answer": "Eyes",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "Throat",
        "Stomach",
        "Blood"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can get the "response_code", "results" with the code that I wrote below

```
$(function() {  

    $.getJSON('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            console.log(key +" or " + val);
        }); 

    });

  });
```

Comment: $.each(data.results, function(key, val)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the results array with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
$(function () {
  $.getJSON('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10', function (data) {
    data.results.forEach(function (result) {
      var question = result.question;
      var incorrect_answers = result.incorrect_answers;
      console.log(question || incorrect_answers);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

#### You just need to loop through `data.results`

You should test to make sure it exists first...like I did below

```js
var data = {
  "response_code": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "category": "Science & Nature",
      "type": "multiple",
      "difficulty": "medium",
      "question": "Which part of the body does glaucoma affect?",
      "correct_answer": "Eyes",
      "incorrect_answers": [
        "Throat",
        "Stomach",
        "Blood"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

if( data.results ){
  
  // jQuery way
  $.each(data.results, function(index, d){
    
    console.log(d.question)
    console.log(d.incorrect_answers)
    
  })
  
  // vanilla JavaScript
  data.results.forEach(function(d, index){
    
    console.log(d.question)
    console.log(d.incorrect_answers)
    
  })
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: do I have to change it to data.results.forEach, can't I use the $.each method of the getJSON?

Comment: You can still use the jQuery `$.each`. I just showed how to do without jQuery

Comment: how do I do it with the key value? just to get inside to the children

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: It wasn't me, I hate when they do that

Comment: just loop through the data again: `$.each(d, function(key, val){  })`

Comment: Yeah, could have say that too, I don't know how, what to type inside of it

Comment: I guess I dont understand what you are trying to do then

Comment: Ok now you wrote both ways, thank you